# Refreshing switches tabs on me

Tags: bug, new-nav

I created a tab for myself with the tags I'm interested it, OR-ed together:

[image]

But if I refresh the page, the tab switches to a new one - with all of my tags AND-ed together:

[image]

Needless to say, this is really annoying.